# running a remote shell script that switches to a user does not return to the issuing local server shell

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, su, sh

When I run a script such as this:

```
ssh -t root@10.10.10.10 '/tmp/somescript.sh'
```

where the script is defined as:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /data/workday/cred
chown -R myuser:myuser /data
su myuser -  # <------- NOTICE THIS ! ! ! ! 
rpm -Uvp --force --nodeps --prefix /data/place /data/RPMs/myrpm.rpm
```

Notice the above **su** command.

If I comment-out the **su** command, the script runs remotely and then my shell prompt returns to where I came from ( same server where I ran the ssh command above )

But leaving the script as listed above, causes the script to complete successfully but the **shell prompt stays on the remote server**.

How can I prevent that ? Making sure that the issuer of the rpm command is a different user than root just a listed ?

Comment: asking the same question on multiple sites is discouraged: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21314886/7552

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the rpm command with sudo:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /data/workday/cred
chown -R myuser:myuser /data
sudo -u myuser rpm -Uvp --force --nodeps --prefix /data/place /data/RPMs/myrpm.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

`su` starts a shell. When you exit that shell, then the rpm command will execute. If you're changing user to execute the rpm command, then

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvp --force --nodeps --prefix /data/place /data/RPMs/myrpm.rpm'  myuser
```